# Designing custom dialler using material design

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design

I'm designing a dialler app using material design, while creating dialler pad should I use 9 buttons as numbers inside a grid layout or is their any other way through which we can build each numbers.

I'm trying to build something like this
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the link below:

https://github.com/IstiN/smartphone